# Изменяются элементы ListView во время прокрутки

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, expandablelistview

Использую кастомный ExpandableListView, с добавлением картинки справа к родительским элементам. На первые 9 элементов все грузится как надо. Но эти же картинки загружаются на все остальные элементы. При прокрутке списка вниз новые картинки начинаются подгружаться. При разворачивании списка, картинки так же меняются. Как будто ID меняется, меняется и картинка на элементе.

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new ParserTask().execute();
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches?launch_year=2017");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        Log.d("JSON:", json);

        ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);

        final ArrayList<Rocket> rockets = getData(json);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, rockets);

        elv.setAdapter(adapter);

        elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPos,
                                        int childPos, long id) {
             //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rockets.get(groupPos).getChild(childPos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //  return false;
                Log.d("URL", rockets.get(groupPos).getChild(childPos));
               Uri address = Uri.parse(rockets.get(groupPos).getChild(childPos));
                Intent openlinkIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
                startActivity(openlinkIntent);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}

//Метод преобразующий JSON в ArrayList с нужными полями
private ArrayList<Rocket> getData(String jsonString) {

    ArrayList<Rocket> rockets = new ArrayList<Rocket>();

    try {
        JSONArray launchesJSONArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        if (launchesJSONArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < launchesJSONArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject rocketJSON = launchesJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject rocketInfo = rocketJSON.getJSONObject("rocket");

                //Конвертация времени
                long dv = Long.valueOf(rocketJSON.getString("launch_date_unix"))*1000;
                Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);


                JSONObject links = rocketJSON.getJSONObject("links");

                String mission_patch = links.getString("mission_patch");
                Log.d("mission_patch", mission_patch);

                Rocket rocket = new Rocket(String.valueOf(new StringBuilder(rocketInfo.getString("rocket_name") +
                        " (flight: ")),
                        String.valueOf(new StringBuilder("Date launch: " +
                                new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mma").format(df))),
                        rocketJSON.getString("details"),
                        links.getString("mission_patch"),
                        new Integer(rocketJSON.getString("flight_number" )),
                        links.getString("video_link"),
                        links.getString("article_link"));
                rockets.add(rocket);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rockets;
}
```

}

`Rocket`

```
 public class Rocket {
private String rocketName;
Integer flightNumber;

private ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();

public Rocket(String rocketName, String dateTime, String details, String mission_patch, Integer flightNumber,
              String videoLink, String wiki){
    this.rocketName = rocketName;
    this.fields.add(dateTime);
    this.fields.add(details);
    this.fields.add(videoLink);
    this.fields.add(wiki);
    this.fields.add(mission_patch);
    this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
}

public String getRocketName() {
    return rocketName;
}

public String getChild(int i){
    return fields.get(i);
}

public Integer getCountChild(){
    return fields.size();
}

public Integer getFlightNumber() {return  this.flightNumber; }
```

}

'CustomAdapter'

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context c;
private static ArrayList<Rocket> rockets;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

HashMap<ImageView, String> imgMap1 = new HashMap<>();


public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Rocket> rockets){
    this.c = c;
    this.rockets = rockets;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return rockets.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return rockets.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return rockets.get(i).getChild(i1);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }

    Rocket r = (Rocket) getGroup(i);

    TextView nameTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    String name = r.getRocketName();
    Integer flightNumber = r.getFlightNumber();
    nameTv.setText(new StringBuilder(name + flightNumber + ")"));

    Log.d("N", String.valueOf(i));
    if (imgMap1.get(img) == null) {
        imgMap1.put(img, r.getChild(4));
        new DownloadImageTask(img).execute(rockets.get(i).getChild(4));
        return view;
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }
    String  child=(String) getChild(i, i1);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    nameTextView.setText(child);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    switch (i1){
        case 2:
            return true;
        case 3:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: блок `if` в адаптере что делает? это очень странная конструкция, но в любом случае она должна возвращать значение для обоих вариантов - когда условие совпадает и когда нет, так как айтемы переиспользуются - те, что уходят за экран подставляются на место тех, которые появляются и если явно не указано, что должно происходить в любом случае (одна ветка if), то будет использовано то, что было ранее при несовпадении условия

Comment: @pavlofff, блок if проверяет есть ли ImageView с текущей картинкой в HashMap. Если нет, (imgMap1.get(img) == null), то добавляем ее, иначе код в условии пропускается и делается просто return. Предлагаете второй return поместить в else?

Comment: @pavlofff, если бы вы подсказали правильную конструкцию if, был бы благодарен.

Comment: этот блок в любом случае должен вернуть именно ту картинку, которая должна находится именно в этом элементе